# IllegalArgumentException with Spring AOP

Tags: spring, inheritance, proxy, spring-aop, illegalargumentexception

*This problem was first reported as [Spring issue #24248](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24248).*

I'm building an application with Spring AOP and I'm using aspects to modify some of my business objects. When I'm starting my application I get the following stacktrace (only the root is shown):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: methods with same signature get() but incompatible return types: [interface main.DomainObjectInterfaceA, interface main.DomainObjectInterfaceB]
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.checkReturnTypes(ProxyGenerator.java:712)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(ProxyGenerator.java:461)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(ProxyGenerator.java:339)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:639)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:719)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:123)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:473)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:355)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    ... 10 more
```

I extracted this in a minimal code snippet from my application to reproduce this stacktrace.

*Remark by [kriegaex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082681/kriegaex): I created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and pushed it to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_SpringTwoInterfacesWithSameMethodName_59486425).*

My domain model consists of three classes:

```java
package main;
public interface DomainObjectInterfaceA {
}
```

```java
package main;
public interface DomainObjectInterfaceB{
}
```

```java
package main;
public class DomainObjectImplementation implements DomainObjectInterfaceA, DomainObjectInterfaceB {

  private int fieldToModifyThroughAspect = 0;

  public int getFieldToModifyThroughAspect() {
    return fieldToModifyThroughAspect;
  }

  public void setFieldToModifyThroughAspect( int aFieldToModify ) {
    fieldToModifyThroughAspect = aFieldToModify;
  }
}
```

Furthermore I have the following two Spring components:

```java
package main;
@Component
public class ComponentImplementation implements ComponentInterfaceA<DomainObjectImplementation>, ComponentInterfaceB<DomainObjectImplementation> {

  public DomainObjectImplementation get() {
    return new DomainObjectImplementation();
  }
}
```

```java
package main;
@org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
@Component
public class Aspect {

  @Pointcut( "execution(public DomainObjectImplementation main.ComponentImplementation.*(..))" )
  public void anyPublicOperation() {
  }

  @AfterReturning( pointcut = "anyPublicOperation()", returning = "aObject" )
  public Object get( Object aObject ) {
    DomainObjectImplementation returningObject = ( DomainObjectImplementation ) aObject;
    returningObject.setFieldToModifyThroughAspect( 5);
    return returningObject;
  }

}
```

The crucial part in reproducing the issue are the following two generic interfaces which are implemented by `ComponentImplementation`:

```java
package main;
public interface ComponentInterfaceA<T extends DomainObjectInterfaceA> {

  T get();

}
```

```java
package main;
public interface ComponentInterfaceB<T extends DomainObjectInterfaceB> {

  T get();

}
```

The above two interfaces share a method with the same signature, but a different generic type. `ComponentImplementation` implements those two interfaces with a class that satisfies both of those generic arguments.

The last two required classes are of course the `Main` class and the `Spring` Config class which are declared below:

```java
package main;
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan( basePackageClasses = Config.class )
public class Config {
}
```

```java
package main;
public class Main {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( Config.class );
    ComponentImplementation bean = context.getBean( ComponentImplementation.class );
    DomainObjectImplementation domainObject = bean.get();

    System.err.println("Aspect modified get method = " + ( domainObject.getFieldToModifyThroughAspect() == 5));
  }

}
```

I also tried to configure `EnableAspectJAutoProxy` with `proxyTargetClass = true`, but then the same exception is thrown with a slightly different stacktrace (namely the JDK proxy vs the Cglib)

The complete dependencies list:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aspectj/aspectjrt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
```

Comment: I attempted a test case with the exact same code copy and pasted. It works for me without any errors/issues.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, but as soon as I use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` it goes away and on the console I see `Aspect modified get method = true`. Please retry and confirm.